# Reflectional symmetries of square pyramid

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, geometry, symmetry

I am trying to find symmetries of square pyramid to color its faces. We have $4$ rotational symmetries such as identity, $90^\circ$ , $180^\circ$, $270^\circ$. The rotational symmetries are clear and sensible. However, when I come to $4$ reflectional symmetries such as with respect to midpoint of two opposite edges and with respect to diagonal of the base square, I confused. The reason is that when I apply the reflectional symmetry, then the square pyramid will not be seen the same, because its direction will reserve. What I meant by "**its direction will reserve**" is that its top point look at above in the original position, but look at bottom when reflectional symmetry applied.

I confused because as far as I know when we apply reflection or rotation, we must obtain the same appearance. Am I wrong in that? If not, how will we obtain its reflections.

**Please be clear in your answer or comment , because I just started learning this topic**

**MORE EXPLANATION:** When I looked at comments, I saw that I could not explain what I meant, so let think a classical square based pyramid and called its lateral faces as $1,2,3,4$ such that
[image: 1]

Now , lets write its symmetries :

- $90^\circ :(1432)$
- $180^\circ :(13)(42)$
- $270^\circ :(1234)$
- Reflection $1$ by midpoints of opposite sides (Think the red line as plane dividing the pyramid into to pieces): $(1)(3)(24)$.

Look at the picture:
[image: 2]

However, when we reflect it like that, we obtain such a appearance:
[image: 3]

- Reflection $2$ by midpoints of opposite sides : $(13)(2)(4)$
- Reflection by diagonal : $(32)(14)$
- Reflection by diagonal : $(34)(12)$

Let's think about "Reflection $1$ by midpoints of opposite sides". When you look at its picture, you will see that its apex pointing out the bottom side while it was pointing out "the sky or above" before reflection. I said that I'm confused, because this pyramid:
[image: 4]

is not the same as the original one:

[image: 5]

However, we must have obtained same appearance. I could not manage to reflect it when the apex pointing out above.

Comment: In 3D reflections are with respect to a *plane*. So for example a reflection w.r.t. the plane determined by the diagonal of the base and the peak is a symmetry of a square pyramid. Because the peak is on the plane of reflection, it stays where it is.

Comment: See also [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2058402/11619), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2317882/11619).

Comment: I imagine that what you mean by a "square pyramid" is like an egyptian pyramid. If such is the case, why should the apex ( = peak ) be transformed into its mirror image through a reflection with respect to the basis plane ?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen i added more explanation . Please read ..

Comment: @JeanMarie i added more explanation . Please read .

Comment: I repeat what I said already. In 3D you reflect with respect to a plane - not w.r.t. a line. In 2D, the usual reflections are w.r.t. a line, but that's because we have one dimension less. Whoever asked you to look at reflections as symmetries surely meant reflections with respect to a plane. One such plane is determined by the peak and midpoints of a pair of opposite sides of the base. You need three (non-collateral) points to specify a plane.  Place the mirror thru that red line in the base AND THE PEAK. Then reflect.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics)#Reflection_through_a_hyperplane_in_n_dimensions). [Another picture](https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/affine/reflection/). Terminology may differ from one (version of a) language (or author) to another.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen it is what i have done in reflection $1$ such that the latheral $1$ and $3$ fixed and $2-4$ changed their position. Right ? However , i could not obtain this configuration while moving this pyramid in $3D$. The only possible way to obtain it reversing the apex $180^\circ$

Comment: You were trying to rotate the pyramid 180 degree about an axis (=a line). The confusion probably arises from the fact that in school geometry an 180 degree rotation of the plane about a point is also called a reflection w.r.t. to that point. More abstractly (and in higher dimensions) we typically call those rotations. A reflection in $n$-dimensions is usually defined to keep an $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace fixed pointwise. So in 3D a reflection keep the points of some plane (=the mirror) fixed. Your transformation only kept  the points on a line fixed.

Comment: Ok. Getting warmer. It sounds like you have discovered the fact that a reflection reverses *handedness*, and you cannot realize it with a motion in 3D any more than you move your left hand to the space of your right hand. Yet there is a reflection of the 3D space that intechanges your left and right hand (place a mirror in between). Such non-rotational symmetries are sometimes included, sometimes they are not.

Comment: Check your book. They should have pictures of reflections and symmetries. Typically of a 2D object. Do observe that you cannot realize the reflection of the base square without lifting it off the plane of the base either. Similarly you could rotate the 3D-pyramid in 4D-space to affect the reflection I'm trying to describe.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen your last comment is what i want to hear. Briefly , you say that we cannot distinguish whether the apex reversed $180^\circ$ in $3D$